# How to use execl in order to pipe multiple processes

Tags: c, shell, operating-system, execl

I am still new to OS domnain. Currently i am trying to implement a shell in C, one of the main feature being the ability to pipe. My question is:
After executing the fork dup and other needed processes how should i write inside the execl in case i have multiple arguments. For example once a I would have a pipe 3 processes like sth | sth | sth other times with two like sth | sth

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have simple pipe like `ls | wc`. It could possibly be visualized like this:

```
        +----+                                    +----+
------> | ls | ---------------------------------> | wc | ------->
(stdin) +----+ (pipe write end)   (pipe read end) +----+ (stdout)
```

Each program needs a separate child process, created with `fork` from the main shell process. Each child-process then calls `exec` as you would usually do.

Generally speaking, for a pipe containing `n` programs, you need `n` processes and `n - 1` pipes. It can be generalized and put into a loop.

Comment: i understand the concept my question was about the execl command. if i have 3 arguments do i have to call all of them in the execl

Comment: @SirScroll You call the `exec` functions just like you would normally do for any other program your shell tries to run.